# Problem NIntegrating over 3D Polygon region with 4 points

Tags: numerical-integration, regions, polygons

I am trying to NIntegrate a non-planar polygonal region defined by 4 points, something like this:

```
p1 = {1, 1, 1};
p2 = {-1, 1, 1};
p3 = {-1, -1, 1};
p4 = {1, -1, 4};
region = Polygon[{p1, p2, p3, p4}];
Show[Graphics3D[region]]
NIntegrate[1, {x, y, z} \[Element] region]
```

And this is the result I get:

[image]

What is the correct way of doing this?
The integral works when the polygon is planar. I could separate the polygon into two triangles, but since the points vary a lot with each iteration of my script that might be an additional issue.

Comment: It says in the documentation for `Polygon` _Degenerate polygons are not valid geometric regions:_ and if you evaluate `RegionQ[region]` it is `False` when region is degenerate.

Comment: I see, thanks. Then what approach would you recommend?

Comment: `region = MeshRegion[{p1, p2, p3, p4}, {Triangle[{1, 2, 3}], Triangle[{1, 3, 4}]}];`

Answer (score 2):

There six interpretation of *polygon* for your situation, one for each edge of the tetrahedron. For each edge of the tetrahedron, the pair of faces may have a different area sum.

```mma
p1 = {1, 1, 1}; 
p2 = {-1, 1, 1}; 
p3 = {-1, -1, 1}; 
p4 = {1, -1, 4}; 
region = Tetrahedron[{p1, p2, p3, p4}]; 
Show[Graphics3D[region]]
NIntegrate[1, Element[{x, y, z}, region]]
TableForm[({#1[[1]], Area[#1[[1]]], #1[[2]], Area[#1[[2]]], Area[#1[[1]]] + Area[#1[[2]]]} & ) /@ 
   Subsets[MeshPrimitives[region, 2], {2}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: The table form output]